# Windows 7 computer suddenly stops responding to mouse

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

I m using Windows 7 on an older Gateway machine that originally ran Vista. I've been using it with no significant problems. When I was playing a game (World of Tanks) the mouse cursor popped to the middle of screen and was unresponsive from then on.  This mouse was a Logitech wireless.  I went through a number of steps, rebooted a few times, started using a known working USB wired mouse plugged into a front panel port, but no response at any time.

In Control Panel and the Device Manager.  I brought up the USB mouse item, and all was reported as normal.  The Hardware tab even said the device was operating normally.
since the keyboard is USB as well and is working fine.  I'm out of ideas.  Anyone here have any?

Comment: What about if you uninstall the mouse and let it auto detect again?

Comment: Haven't tried that.  I will give it a shot.

Comment: @Bilo, make that advice an answer and I will accept it.  I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please uninstall the mouse from `Device Manager` and let it auto detect again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  What I was to uninstall the device driver for the mouse while it was unplugged, and then plugged it back in afterwards.  The driver re-installed, and then the mouse worked again!  Saved!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with your mouse, try an another one. If you think your mouse works fine, then try to switch USB ports with your keyboard.
I hope you have no software problems.

Comment: Two known good mice, one wired the other wireless, and attached to known working USB ports.  It's not a mouse problem.